# Checking existence of lazy loaded child without getting/loading in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, proxy, lazy-loading, parent-child

This should be easy, but I can't seem to figure it out... How can I check if a child on an entity exists without actually getting or fetching it?  The child is lazy loaded right now..

so I have two entities:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B Child { get; set; }
}
class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Blob { get; set; }
}
```

I want to check for existence of B in an instance of A without actually fetching the large blog...  In straight sql I could just check to see if child_id is not null... Is there some way I can query the NHibernate Proxy of B in A?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nm - one can just check for a null value.  Only if a child exists will there be a proxy.

Answer (score 8):

[NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(...)](http://djeeg.blogspot.com/2006/08/nhibernateutilisinitialized.html) will tell you if a proxy object has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The null-value check is the perfect solution : efficient, understandable.